# Citrix : bad rendering on ubuntu 2204

Tags: 22.04, xorg, citrix, icaclient

I use the Citrix Workplace App version 23.3.0.32 on Ubuntu 2204 LTS with X11 (Wayland isn’t supported) installed from the DEB package. When I open an ica file with it it gives me a screen not properly rendered [see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ac90.png)

I have tried to run `/opt/Citrix/ICAClient/util/workspacecheck.sh`
and have installed every package until the script was satisfied that everything necessary is installed.

I then went to https://docs.citrix.com/en-us/citrix-workspace-app-for-linux/system-requirements.html and installed a few more packages.
I have repeatedly tried purging icaclient from my system and made sure that neither the install directory (/opt/Citrix/) nor the one in my home directory (${HOME}/.ICAClient/) are present before reinstalling.

- The logs also seem not to contain any relevant information:

**ICAClient.log**

`$ tail /var/log/citrix/ICAClient.log`

```
2023-05-04 20:05:22.152 [TD] <P567937> citrix-wfica: SSLconnect enter: cs=0xfc179770, context=0xfc171be0 
2023-05-04 20:05:22.925 [EUEM] <P567937> citrix-wfica: VDEUEM: Insufficient Input buffer size: 0 bytes. Required buffer size: 48 bytes 
2023-05-04 20:05:22.925 [EUEM] <P567937> citrix-wfica: VDEUEM: DriverInfo failed. rc = 0x3ec 
2023-05-04 20:05:22.925 [IME] <P567937> citrix-wfica: VDIME: Insufficient Input buffer size: 0 bytes. Required buffer size: 48 bytes 
2023-05-04 20:05:22.925 [MMVD] <P567937> citrix-wfica: VDMM: Insufficient Input buffer size: 0 bytes. Required buffer size: 50 bytes 
2023-05-04 20:05:22.925 [MMVD] <P567937> citrix-wfica: VDMM: DriverInfo failed. rc = 0x3ec 
2023-05-04 20:05:23.398 [TW] <P567937> citrix-wfica: Tw2RealizePalette: DisplayHnd Should not be NULL 
2023-05-04 20:05:23.425 [ALL] <P567937> citrix-wfica: SSL session strength: 128 
2023-05-04 20:05:24.218 [TWI] <P567937> citrix-wfica: Changing window width from 0 to 1 
2023-05-04 20:05:24.218 [TWI] <P567937> citrix-wfica: Changing window height from 0 to 1
```

**syslog**

`$ grep -i wfica /var/log/syslog`

```
May  4 19:27:54 RAB3NHVSG3 citrix-ctxcwalogd[468227]: Process 533992 has named itself "citrix-wfica".
May  4 19:28:10 RAB3NHVSG3 wfica[533992]: Source ID 115 was not found when attempting to remove it
May  4 19:28:36 RAB3NHVSG3 citrix-ctxcwalogd[468227]: Process 534189 has named itself "citrix-wfica".
May  4 19:39:57 RAB3NHVSG3 citrix-ctxcwalogd[468227]: Process 544308 has named itself "citrix-wfica".
May  4 19:40:12 RAB3NHVSG3 wfica[544308]: Source ID 122 was not found when attempting to remove it
May  4 19:52:12 RAB3NHVSG3 citrix-ctxcwalogd[468227]: Process 557500 has named itself "citrix-wfica".
May  4 19:52:26 RAB3NHVSG3 wfica[557500]: Source ID 144 was not found when attempting to remove it
May  4 20:05:22 RAB3NHVSG3 citrix-ctxcwalogd[468227]: Process 567937 has named itself "citrix-wfica".
May  4 20:05:38 RAB3NHVSG3 wfica[567937]: Source ID 128 was not found when attempting to remove it
```

Comment: can someone had citrix work on ubuntu, share with me the configs files for citrix :